# Python arguments, for in items

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'd like to pass a list of integers as an argument to a python script.

Example code:

```
items = sys.argv[1]
for item in items:
    print item
```

My command would be:

```
python myscript.py 101,102,103
```

The problem is that 'for in' is giving me each digit rather than each item as delimited by the commas.

I'm sure there's an easy answer.  How do I loop through the delimted values rather than single digits?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the command line arguments are separated by spaces. The comma separated numbers are coming in as a single string, and the `for` is splitting the string into characters. You need to split it by commas: `items.split(',')`. Once you do that you'll find that you still have strings, so you need to convert each string to an integer.

```
items = argv[1]
for item in items.split(','):
    print int(item)
```

Comment: Lovely.  Yes, that sounds like it.  I was half expecting a 'Google is your friend' comment or similar.  I enjoy answering easy questions on here, so I suppose others must : ).  Thank you and happy new year.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use directly :

```
python myscrypt.py 101 102 103
```

and

```
items = sys.argv
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that'll do it.  The script will have several other arguments for other purposes, and the list of integers in the first won't always be the same length.

Comment: You can pass a string in the command line such as `"101,102,103"` and use Python's `split` function to take the different arguments out of the string then ;)

Answer (score 2):

Split the input:

```
items = sys.argv[1].split(',')
for item in items:
    print item
```

Answer (score 2):

The command line argument is passed to your script as a single string so you need to split it using the ',' as a delimiter to return individual integers.

```
items = sys.argv[1]
for item in items.split(','):
    print item
```